# Low reputation/karma count, deleted user profiles - did something happen?

Tags: discussion

Just started revisiting and reading through some topics.

I noticed a couple of "power" users[1] in regards to 2014 have either changed their names, lost a lot of reputation points or deleted their profiles.

What on earth is going on? Does someone not like tex.sx or is there a new opponent in the stackexchange or latex world?

:(

[1] I'd say in this context, these are users who basically deliver a lot of helpful and/or supportive content. Whether it is through posting answers or helpful comments or giving rep for finding bounties aways or other means.

Comment: There were some name changes. But it depends on what you mean by "'power' users".

Comment: @Werner: Most probably top reviewers and users with more than > 50k rep are 'power users', but I leave it to the OP to define this term. (And I am one of the name changers (well, will return after the 30-days period of renaming prohibition), but I am not a power user of course)

Comment: Some users give (almost all) their rep founding bounties to support other users. They always have low rep, but a high amount of badges.

Comment: @Werner Edited my op. :)

Comment: There is some truth to what you feel but not that easy to quantify. Especially after that review system and some hail-SO-rules users' arrival, it does indeed feels less fun but maybe others will join and balance it out. Or it would be a tasteless/boring place, you can never know. As usual the newest member of the pack becomes the most vicious towards the next new member.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think anything happened, except perhaps *life*. :-)

This site is a thriving place, but it's not anyone's entire life. Stuff happens. Priorities change. People need to take breaks.

I (not that I'm a 'power user') was all but absent for a few months, and now I am back. That may happen again, and it could have happened for some of the 'power users'.

The bottom line is that this community is comprised of volunteers. I like spending time here (and I'm sure others feel the same) because it's fun to solve problems and learn lots of new things. But sometimes things come up and "something's gotta give". Certain people not spending as much time here doesn't necessarily mean there's been a falling-out. (And nothing that I've seen indicates that that's the case.)

To address the other items in the question (some of this has already been mentioned in the comments):

- Several users are known for being prolific [Investor](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/badges/45/investor)s/[Promoter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/badges/46/promoter)s, transferring significant portions of their Reputation into bounties to encourage high-quality content on the site.
- One user (that I know of, maybe more) has a habit of changing his/her display name roughly as often as the new moon occurs.

Answer (score 2):

I'm one of the Trusted users (this at least has a definition) who's changed his name. I know about another recent name change of a fairly active user. I mention it clearly in my profile.

If you met someone "power" with very low rep, it could be that you met a spammer. They like to adopt other community members' names in hope for quickly gaining reputation that would allow them to do worse things. Needed to say, you'd be quite Lucky Duke since most of the spam posts are zapped within seconds or minutes.